# Access children of Custom Control wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

Being quite experienced with WPF `UserControl`, I thought of trying out custom controls. Here's what I have so far :

**Generic.XAML**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testapp">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:testcontrol}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:testcontrol}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="test"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**CustomControl.Cs**

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

public class testcontrol : System.Windows.Controls.Control
{
    public TextBlock tb;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        tb = this.GetTemplateChild("tb");
    }

    public static test()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (testcontrol), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (testcontrol)));
    }

    private void testcontrol_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Text = "Abc";
    }
}
```

Now when the `MouseDown` event is fired, the `TextBlock`'s text changes which means the textblock is found/accessible...

But when i do the same thing from my window as follows :

```
 private void test()
 {
     testcontrol tt = new testcontrol();
     tt.tb.Text = "abc";
 }
```

a `NullReferenceException` is thrown. I wonder why it fails to find the `TextBlock`? Any explanation will be highly appreciated.

One last thing, I just got started with custom controls so please be kind to indicate if my approach is correct :)

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to use a control which is not initialized ---- if you see the tb is initialized on `OnApplyTemplate` function. Any specific reason why are you creating a new instance, instead of using the rendered control (defined in XAML).

Comment: Wait...how is it not initialized??! @user1672994

Comment: where does the tb is initialized in your code? --- `OnApplyTemplate`. Does it  being called when you do `testcontrol tt = new testcontrol()`??

Comment: @user1672994 is right. You should not put `TextBlock tb;` in your code-behind, but simply specify it in XAML *only*. This will correctly initialize it. I'm not sure about whether it will be initialized before the `OnApplyTemplate` method, but it will certainly be initialized automatically.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow , you are wrong....In custom control, children can't be accessed using names .... I must use `GetTemplateChildren` to get the textblock

Comment: @user1672994 , how do i initialize it ? i tried calling `tt.OnApplyTemplate` but no luck

Comment: Yep, I think it's template namescope weirdness that causes this sort of issue. It's still eventually a control Zack, and it's still going to be in the visual tree. Meaning you can use the usual visualtree iteration to go find it. You presumably know, but making it instead go find your data with binding would of course be more usual.

Comment: Let's change the perspective here. Instead of you trying updating text property of `TextBlock` defined in  `Custom-Control` as object in a external window method, you work based on dependency property defined in Custom Contorl (which should update the `TextBlock` property)?

Comment: @user1672994 , can u plz give a code sample ?

Comment: @zackraiyan - check my response.

Comment: @zackraiyan *"you are wrong....In custom control, children can't be accessed using names .... I must use GetTemplateChildren"* well tell me, what do you pass to `GetTemplateChildren` in your code sample? The *name* of the child, don't you? ;)

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow , wait!! I think u opened my eyes a bit ...!!!! I'll try something and come back

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow , can u help me a bit ? The issue is i'm in vs 2015 and everytime i reopen my proj,the custom control gets broken..There's error all over but the first line `public class testcontrol : System.Windows.Controls.Control` saying : `Base class "control" cannot be specified for class "testcontrol" cannot be different from the base class "Resource Dictionary" or one of it's partial dependencies` .. How do i fix it ?!!!

Comment: @zackraiyan as the error states, in your XAML you have the opening tag `<ResourceDictionary ...`. You cannot add code behind files (.cs) to `ResourceDictionaries`. The way to go is create a C# (.cs) file for your control only and define its look in some other `ResourceDictionary`. Ask again if you need further help.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow , wait what ? When i create a new custom control,i get a Generic.xaml file.... Isn't it where i should put all the XAML or so ?? All the tutorials do so..and why does this error pop up only when i reopen vs whereas it keeps working and building if i don't close vs ?

Comment: As long as you didn’t try to add code behind to the `Generic.xaml`, you’re good to go. I can’t help you further than that without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow, this is the actual code..... I am not adding and code behind for the xaml file ... I am rather putting all the code in the default .cs file i get when i created the control

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow , i fixed the bug but back to my question .... please tell me what to do ?!!

Comment: You should do as @user1672994 told you and use bindings instead. They will resolve all your issues.

Comment: can you give me a sample of how to access a rectangle(suppose named as `rect1`) from the custom control so that i can create an event handler for it from my WINDOW ?? please i need this badly....

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow, let me tell u my whole scenario ... i am generating the custom control in a loop and adding them to a grid...I have a textblock and rectangle in the custom control.....Now, i cannot just apply code to the custom control's click even because i need to have different click(or mouseDown) events for both the textblock and rectangle.....what to do now?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow , my scenario is almost the same as [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6199709-4664-4cd5-aaa6-224d2b20dc5c/customcontrol-cant-access-xaml-style-from-codebehind-before-initializing-object?forum=wpf)...Anyway , just curios , what would be the vb equivalent of the code `yourCustomControl.Loaded += (ss, ee) => { /*access Rectangle here */ };` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed on comments, you should use the Dependency Property or Routed Events to update the child templated parent instead of direct accessing.

Below is simple example of Custom Control which has Header (TextBlock) before it.

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PreText", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
public class ExtendedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PreTextDependency = DependencyProperty.Register("PreText", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedTextBox));

    public string PreText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PreTextDependency);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(PreTextDependency, value);
        }
    }

    private TextBlock preTextBlock;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        preTextBlock = GetTemplateChild("PreText") as TextBlock;
        Binding preTextBinding = new Binding("PreText");
        preTextBinding.Source = this;
        preTextBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        preTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, preTextBinding);
    }
}
```

XAML of this `ExtendedTextBox`:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <Style x:Key="ExtendedTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:ExtendedTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ExtendedTextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding PreText}" Name="PreText" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

How to define in XAML :

```
    <local:ExtendedTextBox x:Name="extendedTextBox" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ExtendedTextBoxStyle}" Text="Some Text!!" PreText="Pre Text :" />
```

Now how you should update the template child Value (I've give a name of `extendedTextBox`):

```
this.extendedTextBox.PreText = "I'm clicked";
```

Comment: sorry to say but this will not save me entirely....i also need to access some controls such as rectangles and create their event handlers such as `MouseDown` fron the window.....can u suggest some other way?

Comment: Why do you need to access an element that is part of the control's template from a window in the first place? The event handlers should be hooked up in the control itself.

Comment: The only way would be hooking up Commands, Routed Events (event handlers) and dependency property.

Comment: @user1672994 , the answer almost solved my problem...can you help me a bit more plz ?As you've created a `PreText` property for the textblock which works as a text , can you please show me an example on how to create a property for the `Image` control's `Source` property ? and also an example of Routed Event to handle the rectangle's `MouseDown` would help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could put this extension method in a helper class

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetVisualChildren<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent == null)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

        if (child is T t)
        {
            yield return t;
        }

        foreach (T childrensChild in child.FindVisualChildren<T>())
        {
            yield return childrensChild;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
testcontrol tt = new testcontrol();
IEnumerable<TextBlock> allTextBlocks = tt.GetVisualChildren<TextBlock>();
```

to get **all `TextBlock`s inside your `testcontrol`**.

---

For your case especially, you could use

```
testcontroll tt = new testcontrol();
IEnumerable<TextBlock> allTextBlocks = tt.GetVisualChildren<TextBlock>();
TextBlock tb = allTextBlocks.Single(t => t.Name = "tb");

if(tb != null)
{
    tb.Text = "abc";
}
```

---

I'm not sure if [`FindTemplateChild<T>`](https://www.visiblox.com/docs/Visiblox/4.0/WRT/html/991fb1de-4099-152f-296d-a5f57dae4840.htm) could be of use here; at least it's already inbuilt, so you could give it a try.

Comment: @zackraiyan sorry, I added the missing parantheses to the `tt.GetVisualChildren` call. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You want me to put the code in the custom control itself ?

Comment: Also,sorry to say but your code isn't helpful enough...You considered that there'll be only one textblock which is not the case always

Comment: @zackraiyan, no, put the `GetVisualChildren` method in a helper / extension class (it's already prepared for use as an extension method). I will edit the answer again to make it more clear.

Comment: @zackraiyan well you're free to write your own code for that cases ;) `tt.GetVisualChildren<TextBlock>()` returns **all** `TextBlock`s contained in the `testcontrol` - you have to do the filtering yourself.

Comment: i will be glad if u edit your answer for universal purposes :)

Comment: Though this answer wouldn't help but i'll still upvote it because you spent your valuable time explaining to me :)