# How can I get controls inside the custom control?

Tags: wpf

I made a Custom Control, here is the XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Sheet}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Sheet}">
                    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="71"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="18"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}">
                            <Grid x:Name="G">
                                <Border Background="#59217346"></Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Button Background="#e6e6e6" BorderBrush="#999999" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Visibility="Collapsed">◢</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I need to access the Grid which `x:Name="G"` to add&remove its children.

I found a topic about this:[Access children of Custom Control wpf c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096254/access-children-of-custom-control-wpf-c-sharp)

It suggests using a `Dependency Property`. However, I can't bind the `Children` of the `Grid` yet.

There is another solution by using a `VisualTreeHelper` to get the `Grid` directly.

Meanwhile, the `VisualTreeHelper` can only get the child while the control is completely loaded, or it only returns 0 children.

I need to initialize its children while creates it and hardly wait the control loaded. For example, whenever I set a `Dependency Property` Rows of the Custom Control to 4, the `Grid` which `x:Name="G"` will add&remove its `RowDefinition` to 4.

How can I solve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `CustomControl` override [`OnApplyTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate?view=netframework-4.8) and use  [`FrameworkElement.GetTemplateChild(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild?view=netframework-4.8) to get a named element that is part of the template. `OnApplyTemplate` is invoked when the controls visual tree is created (template applied) and measured, but before the `Loaded` event.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
  var grid = GetTemplateChild("G") as Grid;
  grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
}
```

Comment: It is great! That's it.

Answer (score 0):

use `var g = (Grid)Control.Template.FindName("G",Control)`, here Control is the name of the the control you set the style to. it can be `this`. Cast what it returns to the the type of the the "G". Here (Grid). Then access all the children by `saying g.Children[index]` you can access the its properties like `g.Row` `g.RowDefinations`;